# What is the best Stack Exchange site for asking computer networking questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Especially questions related to problems I have with my Internet connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) is perfect for questions of setting up a home network or your personal Internet connection.